# Does async make everything inside it asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

According to MDN,

> the async function declaration defines an asynchronous function

I understand it as the function will be treated as an async process just like `setTimeout` or some database request. For example, in the example below, the process should output "main" somewhere between the numbers.

```
let func2 = async () => {
   for (let i = 0; i < 51; i ++) {
       console.log(i);
   }
}

(async () => {
    func2();
    console.log("main");
})()
```

However, "main" is always consoled at the end like the whole process is synchronous. What am I understanding wrong?

If the synchronous code is still synchronous, what's the purpose of `async`? Only allows `await` inside it and provide some fancy way to return a `Promise`?

Comment: You are correct; adding a keyword does not magically make code asynchronous.

Comment: JavaScript is technically synchronous, as it can only run one thing at a time. `async` is basically telling the parser that it can run that function at a later time. When it does run then that is the only thing that is currently running https://medium.com/@kvosswinkel/is-javascript-synchronous-or-asynchronous-what-the-hell-is-a-promise-7aa9dd8f3bfb

Comment: *"Only allows await inside it and provide some fancy way to return a Promise?"* Pretty much, but it's very fancy since it splits complex nested control statements into a promise chain.

Comment: Javascript is single threaded, so you will not get this out of order even if the code was async.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I saw somewhere that JavaScript can switch between processes so it behave similar to multi thread. That’s why I thought it would switch between main process and async function which makes the two process parallel

Comment: @zhangjinzhou I think what you saw is that JavaScript can run worker processes, which is how JavaScript can simulate threading (not real threading), but all this is, is another node process with a communication link between the process and the main process so you are actually running 2 process. Whereas when you have true threading, you have 1 process that can run multiple threads at once in the same process. JavaScript is 1 thread per process.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn This is where I saw it: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Does async make everything inside it asynchronous?

No.  It does not.  The code in your function still runs synchronously and will block the event loop while it is running.

> If the synchronous code is still synchronous, what's the purpose of async? Only allows await inside it and provide some fancy way to return a Promise?

Yes, it is primarily for `await`.

But, there are also some times when the fact that it automatically wraps your code with a promise is useful.  For example, it automatically catches any thrown exceptions and turns them into a rejected promise.  Sometimes that is useful.  For an example of this other usefulness, see the "Error Handling" section of this article: [6 Reasons Why JavaScript’s Async/Await Blows Promises Away](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9#9b6e).

But, the primary function of the `async` keyword is to define a function in which you can use `await`.  This is how the designers of ES7 decided to make `await` work.

FYI, if there's an `await` in the function that awaits a promise, then that will cause the function to return early at the point of the `await`.  It will return at that point and return a promise.  The operation that you are awaiting will have started and the rest of the function will not execute until after the awaited promise is resolved.  So, using an `await` makes some of the code get executed later.  But, as with the code before the `await`, even when the function resumes running after the `await` has resolved, your Javascript in that function is still synchronous and blocking (until another `await` or until a `return`).

Wrapping it in a promise and detecting when it's done with `.then()` will postpone when the `.then()` handler is called until the next tick of the event loop.  So, then `.then()` will be slightly delayed because you wrapped it in a promise and then used `.then()`, but the timing of when your code runs does not change.  It is still synchronous and blocking.

In Javascript, the only ways to take synchronous code and make it asynchronous are:

1. **Run it in another process** and use interprocess communication to communicate back the results.
2. **Rewrite your code in a native code add-on** that uses native threads or some other OS asynchronous interface to do the actual work and then offer an asynchronous interface to Javascript from your add-on (usually an interface that returns a promise or notifies completion via a callback).  This is now node.js asynchronous functions such as `fs.readFile()` work.  They have a native code implementation that returns immediately, then uses native threads in the implementation and notifies completion via a callback.
3. **Use some node.js add-on that does some of this for you.**  There are add-ons that purport to offer threads.
4. **Use node.js threads in node version 10.5+** and program with the restrictions that they require.  Here's an article on the topic: [Threads in Node 10.5.0: a practical intro](https://medium.com/dailyjs/threads-in-node-10-5-0-a-practical-intro-3b85a0a3c953)

Comment: Thanks for the link about 10.5 threads. First I'm hearing about that!

Comment: I also noticed your FYI part. Can we say once there is an await inside async function, return will be useless?

Comment: @zhangjinzhou - No, not useless. `return` will set the resolved value of the promise.  The function will have actually returned to the caller an unresolved promise a long time ago.  So your `return` statement will finally resolve that promise and set the resolved value.

Comment: I'd add web workers to the list of true async methods:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 5):

No, the body inside the async function runs when it is called but pauses for `await` expressions. If there is nothing to `await`, the function will just run like a normal function with the exception that it returns a promise.

However if there is an `await`, execution is paused and the event loop continue. When the awaited promise resolves sometime after the current event loop has finished, it picks up where it left off. For example compare when "main" is logged here vs. your example.

```js
let func2 = async () => {
    console.log("Start")
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
        if(i == 5) {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200))
        }
        console.log(i);
    }
 }
 
 (async () => {
     func2().then(() => console.log('done'));
     console.log("main");
 })()
```

Another way to think about `async` functions is to consider their relationship to [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*). I like to think of `await` as a sort of `yield`. For example the only thing we need to change in the body of `func2` to get the same behavior is swapping `await` for `yield`:

```js
function* func2() {
  console.log("Start")
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i == 5) {
      yield new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0))
    }
    console.log(i);
  }
  return "done"
}

let gen = func2()
gen.next().value.then(() => console.log(gen.next().value))

console.log("main")
```

`async`/`await` just makes this easier and a little more intuitive for common use cases.