# Increment from asyncfunction is safe in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, worker

```
var i=0

async function a(){
 i++     
}

a();
```

Can above code run safely? Even if Javascript is singlethread, especially during read+modify+write operation, another working thread can operate the same operation in async function.

Comment: unsure what is async about that code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does async make everything inside it asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201786/does-async-make-everything-inside-it-asynchronous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an `async` function is invoked, it runs synchronously until an `await` happens inside the function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#description

Therefore, you can rely on `i++` happening synchronously if it happens prior to any `await` statements in the function.

As your question acknowledges, Javascript is single threaded (unless you use web workers, but those are isolated from one another).

Use some kind of [semaphore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semaphore) if you want to ensure that two different async methods do not adversely interleave with one another while modifying shared variables.

Comment: What I would like to hear was that I can rely on i++ synchronously in async function but it could be performance issue isn't it? Beacuse i++ is io operation and that means cpu waits idle while another operation waits.

Comment: @Erdal76t `i++` is not an I/O operation. I/O means reading or writing to a web socket or file, making HTTPS requests, etc. There is no performance issue. To be clear: if you have an async function, and there is not an `await` anywhere inside it, it will act as if it is not an async function at all and will execute like a synchronous function (even if you use await when calling it). If there is an `await` somewhere inside it, then the non-await code inside that async function still executes synchronously. There is no multi-threading in javascript except for web workers.

Comment: Ok, I thought that read+modify+write operation is I/O operation, because streams work on the memory read+modify+write operation. Inputstream and outputstream. But I understand your point; out of (await)s, it runs synchronously in the function.